# Why isn't horizontal advance enough to properly format a glyph?

Tags: c++, fonts, rendering, freetype

I am making a simple text renderer with vulkan and I am using freetype to format my text.

I read the freetype tutorial and I have come up with the following function:

```
void Scribe::CreateSingleLineGeometry(const string &text, ScGeomMetaInfo &info,
    ScGeomtry &geometry)
{
    float texture_length = info.texture_len;
    float h_offset = info.h_offset;

    float char_l = info.char_len;
    float v_anchor = info.v_offset;

    auto &vertices = geometry.first;
    auto &indices = geometry.second;

    auto length = max(ft_face->bbox.xMax - ft_face->bbox.xMin,
        ft_face->bbox.yMax - ft_face->bbox.yMin);
    for(auto &c: text)
    {
        auto glyph_index = FT_Get_Char_Index(ft_face, c);
        auto error = FT_Load_Glyph(ft_face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_NO_HINTING);

        auto metrics = ft_face->glyph->metrics;
        float g_height = metrics.height;
        float g_bearing = metrics.horiBearingY;
        float correction = 1.0 - (g_height) / float(length) -
            float(metrics.horiBearingY - g_height) / float(length);

        correction *= char_l;
        float bearingX = char_l * float(metrics.horiBearingX) / float(length);
        // Insert the vertex positions and uvs into the returned geometry
        float h_coords[] = {h_offset + bearingX, h_offset + bearingX + char_l};
        float v_coords[] = {v_anchor + correction, v_anchor + correction + char_l};
        auto glyph_data = glyph_map[glyph_index];
        float tex_h_coords[] = {glyph_data.lt_uv.x, glyph_data.rb_uv.x};
        float tex_v_coords[] = {glyph_data.lt_uv.y, glyph_data.rb_uv.y};
        for(int x=0; x<2; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<2; y++) {
                vertices.insert(end(vertices), {h_coords[x], v_coords[y], 0});
                vertices.insert(end(vertices), {tex_h_coords[x], tex_v_coords[y]});
            }
        }

        // Setup the indices of the current quad
        // There's 4 vertices in a quad, so we offset each index by (quad_size * num_quads)
        uint delta =  4 * info.c_num++;
        indices.insert(end(indices), {0+delta, 3+delta, 1+delta, 0+delta, 3+delta, 2+delta});
        h_offset += char_l * float(metrics.horiAdvance) / float(length) + 0.03;
    }
}
```

In particular I want to emphasize the line:

`h_offset += char_l * float(metrics.horiAdvance) / float(length) + 0.03;`

That 0.03 at the end of the line doesn't come from anywhere, I inserted it there to make things look good.

This is the result with that extra offset:

[image]

Which I think looks pretty good. However, if I were to remove the extra offset:

`h_offset += char_l * float(metrics.horiAdvance) / float(length);`

[image]

I get something that doesn't look right at all. Why isn't the advance enough to correctly format the font?

Comment: *Which I think looks pretty good.* No, it doesn’t The characters are too far apart by a HUGE amount.

Comment: Which version of Freetype? Also, both images look pretty terrible.... but most importantly, you can't really style text "one letter at a time" without checking GSUB and GPOS for substitution (first) and kerning/positioning (second). A good place to ask in addition to stackoverflow is the https://typedrawers.com typography forum. All the big names hang out there, and you're more likely to get a good answer there than you are here.